# Php mailer not displaying an error when I try to send email to a non-existing email

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Below is my code. $to_address adrress in that email is a non-existing email. Is there any way to get an error when we send email to a non-existing email.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once("lib/class/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); //the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

$from_address=  "info@gmail.com";
$to_address = "testq@gmail.com";


try {
  $mail->AddAddress($to_address, 'Tom');
  $mail->SetFrom($from_address, 'Google');
  $mail->Subject = 'testing subject';
  $mail->Body = 'Testing body content';
  $mail->Send();
  echo "Message Sent OK\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```

Initially I was using mail(). I changed to php mailer only to get Error details.

Thanks,
Sinaj

Comment: You're using an old version of PHPMailer, and I suggest you base your code on [the gmail example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) provided with it.

Answer (score -1):

How should PHPMailer know that it is wrong emailadres? It's just a wrapper that will create a request to the given SMTP server, which will handle it.

If you want to know that something went wrong, your address need to be in the header (the FROM part), so you'll get an error email.

Try it with an emailclient (online, offline, doesn't matter) and try to send a mail to a non-existing address. You won't get an error either.

Comment: That's not 100% true, many mail servers actually do send you a mail with that the mail could not be send to the user because the email does not excist.

Comment: So... the SMTP server will send a mail that is did not exists. That's what I'm saying. It's not that the SMTP will throw an error.

Comment: Yeap that's true, but I think that that's the 'question' of the guy who asked the question. Your response pretty much answered his question.

Comment: @Blaatpraat thanks for your comment. but if the from mail is also non-existing it does not throw an error.

Comment: Actually if you want a bounce response, it's not the `From` header you need to put your address in, it's the `Sender` PHPMailer property (not a header) which is used as the SMTP envelope sender, which is where bounces are sent.